# What's merchant account for in Braintree?

Tags: braintree

as the title says, what is the merchant account for in Braintree?

I am working on a project that requires payment system. Some of the users can receive funds from other users. Whenever there is a transaction, portion of the paid amount need to go directly to the user who provided the service, and small portion of the amount comes to me.

If I understood correctly, Braintree has following structure.

Braintree account -> Merchant account -> Customer account

So here is the questions.

1. List item
2. What is the merchant account for exactly.
3. Is it possible to make multiple merchant account for those users who need to receive payments?
4. Is it possible to transfer funds from my account to other merchant accounts?

I have search Braintree docs but it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a bit more information about your first question?

2. I believe you are referring to a Braintree Submerchant account, which is a merchant that only exists with a [Braintree Marketplace account](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/overview).
3. With Braintree Marketplace transactions, you can only split funds between two parties; yourself (the master merchant, and a single sub merchant account).  You cannot split between multiple sub merchants.
4. Braintree only allows you to receive funds from transactions.  You cannot transfer funds directly to a sub merchant.  This would have to be done outside of Braintree.